# Mac (Mojave) asks for VPN authentication but no VPN exists

Tags: networking, macos, vpn

After messing around with various Mac OS betas, I wiped my drive, installed Mojave beta, and migrated settings from a timemachine backup.

I now get a popup asking for a VPN password - "VPN Connection - Please Enter Your Authentication Details". It reappears instantly after clicking cancel or ok.

I suspect this is due to some ancient remnants of an old VPN which I no longer have or use (CactusVPN), but I have no idea of how to track the bits down. There are no VPN entries in my Network System Prefs.

So, in terminal, how do I work out and delete whatever is trying to send all my internet traffic through the non-existent VPN? Are there network config files that might have old VPN entries?

Comment: This might help you out https://github.com/AkarshSatija/ipsec-vpn-mojave-tool

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up on this after extensive internets research, and restored a timemachine backup.

From my research, this problem has cropped up in other MacOS betas, and has never really been answered (from what I can find).

Things to try:

- Some people report the problem being fixed when installing the next beta/update. So you can try waiting it out...
- The popup is **neagant**, and sometimes is actually asking for your keychain credentials, rather than VPN credentials (this did not work for me, but has worked for others).